# ¿Es posible ajustar el formato de números en SQL Server en relación a un país?

Tags: sql-server

Tenemos un sistema que gestiona informes de una base de datos SQL Server configurada con el idioma Inglés. Al realizar el siguiente query de ejemplo:

```
select campo from table
```

donde "campo" es de tipo numérico, el resultado es el siguiente:

```
433391.000000
```

El formato correcto debería ser 433.391,000000. Lo que quiero lograr es que el numero que devuelva el query tenga el formato correspondiente a cada país desde donde se realiza la consulta. Por ejemplo, si ejecuto la consulta desde Estados Unidos, el valor deberia ser 433,391.000000 y si lo ejecuto desde Chile deberia ser 433.391,000000.

He intentado anteponer

```
SET Language Spanish
```

pero el resultado es el mismo (entiendo que eso solamente afecta a las fechas).

No quiero utilizar CONVERT o FORMAT ya que tendría que intervenir el query dependiendo del país.

Comment: Me temo que así como lo planteas no será posible, ya que el servidor de base de datos siempre toma el formato de la región que tiene configurado, a menos que le indiques algún formato en específico. Esto es del lado de la base de datos, pero, si pudieras dar más detalles como si lo utilizas en una aplicación de .Net o Java, ya sería más fácil *setear* un formato del lado del cliente (estoy especulando nada más, es a modo de ejemplo)

Comment: En este caso seria de una aplicación PHP desde un servidor Linux. He leído tambien que se puede setear un lenguaje específico a un usuario pero lamentablemente no afecta el formato de los números.

Comment: Sería más sencillo darle formato según cada país del lado del cliente ya que ahí sí se podría dar formato según el país donde realizas la consulta :)

Comment: Te refieres en el lado del código, en este caso PHP?

Comment: Exacto, directamente en el código de PHP

Comment: Eso es justamente lo que estoy tratando de evitar ya que mediante esta aplicación en particular no es posible.